# Alternatives to Oracle CLOB for Storing JSON

Tags: json, oracle, clob, varchar2

Are there any other alternative for storing large amounts of data other than `CLOB` in Oracle 10g?
The maximum size of JSON file that I need to store in this field is 150Kb. Can I use `VARCHAR2` or `NTEXT` for this purpose? The content of JSON file may be copied as text too if it is necessary to avoid using a `CLOB`.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: is there a reason that you don't want to use CLOB?

Comment: No, there is no alternative. The maximum size for a `varchar` is 4k, so you can't use that. `CLOB` is your only choice if you want to store more. In 12.1.0.2 you could also use the new `json` data type (note the .0.2 This is not available in 12.1.0.1)

Comment: I am using JPA and hibernate. I want to retrieve the contents of this field as string. The blob and clob make this task hell. Stuck with that process for days now and got the answer for the questions somewhat like this at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756432/converting-blob-from-oracle-db-to-string
which is still not useful for a newbie like me.
I would like to go for something a bit more easier.

Comment: So your **real** question is: How do I use the `CLOB` data type with Hibernate?

Comment: anything which works will do. But i could not get any answers for the first one that is why going for this one. Please share if you have a solution for any of the problem...

Comment: @RBz: That mentioned question is non-sense. The questioner does not understand a difference between binary data(Oracle BLOB, java: byte[]) and string data(Oracle CLOB, jave String). Also note that BLOB, CLOB is something like file handler. It is ONLY valid within context of the SAME connection and the SAME transaction. You can not pass it to "another" context and return the connection into connection pool then.

Comment: I once had to remove all CLOBs from my app because the client's DBAs wanted all columns displayed when issuing raw `SELECT * FROM foo` at SQL*Plus prompt. Seriously.

Comment: Since you are talking about JSON ... just in case you are working with XML data you could use the specific data type sys.xmltype

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 10g, the maximum size of a `VARCHAR2` or `NVARCHAR2` column is only 4kb. Under 12c, if you have the `MAX_STRING_SIZE` server property set to `EXTENDED`, this limit [can be increased to 32kb](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/refrn10321.htm#REFRN10321), but still nowhere near 150kb.

You will either need to use `CLOB`, or break your 150kb down into 4kb chunks.

One option for breaking down your data is to store the data in a table where each row represents one line of the file:

```
file_id     line_id     line_data
---------------------------------
1           1           this
1           2           is
1           3           where
1           4           your
1           5           data
1           6           lives
```

Alternatively, if you can upgrade to 12c, you can take advantage of [native JSON support](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6246).

Comment: One last thing, i know BLOB is stored as binary,but is it wrong to store a json file with menu details in a BLOB field. What may be the consequences?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand - JSON isn't binary encoded, so I don't know why you'd use a BLOB...

Comment: @RBz - BLOB means binary data. Even if you do know that it is in fact a "string" nobody else (except you personally) knows which encoding was used. Was is ASCII, UTG-8 or EBDIC? Since the database does not know the encoding scheme, it can not index it as it was a string. For example you can not use full text search on BLOB. Also the Java app MUST know the charset when you convert byte[], into String. In your case usage of BLOB means, the database can not (and will not) care what exactly is stored inside.

Comment: JSON data in the database is textual, but the text can be stored using data type BLOB, as well as VARCHAR2 or CLOB. When possible, Oracle recommends that you use BLOB storage. In particular, doing so obviates the need for any character-set conversion (see JSON: Character Sets and Character Encoding in Oracle Database).